# Accessing variables outside of closure

Tags: javascript, oop

```
var MyClass = (function () {

    var _data;

    var cls = function () { };

    cls.prototype = {

        init: function(data){
            _data = data;
        }
    };

    cls.foo = _data;
    cls.bar = 1;

    return cls;
})();

var someData = { foo: true };

var cls = new MyClass();
cls.init(someData);

console.log(MyClass.foo); //undefined
console.log(MyClass.bar); //1
```

Why isn't `MyClass.foo` set here? It is being set in the `init()` method which I run above it. Hence it should return `{ foo: true }`. What did I miss?

Comment: You're setting `cls.foo = _data` before `_data` has data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cls.foo = _data;` will not alias `cls.foo` to `_data`. It simply copies `_data`'s value, which at the time the line is executed is `undefined`.

Either set `cls.foo` inside `init`, or (better) make `cls.foo` dynamic, as `function() { return _data; }`.

Comment: Even better, make `cls.foo` an accessor property - `Object.defineProperty(cls, "foo", { get: function () { return _data; } })`.

Comment: @AaditMShah I would like a cross browser solution, though :)

Comment: @AaditMShah: Indeed. Thanks. I'm not that hip on JS 1.8.5 yet.

Comment: @Johan - Then just set `cls.foo = data` inside `init`. Simple.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want:

```
function MyClass() { }

MyClass.prototype.init = function (data) {
    MyClass.foo = data;
};

MyClass.bar = 1;
```

Now it'll work as expected:

```
var someData = { foo: true };

var cls = new MyClass;
cls.init(someData);

console.log(MyClass.foo);
console.log(MyClass.bar);
```

See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/gTDZk/